# Calculating median with DataSketches

Tags: druid

Using Apache Druid, I'm trying to find the right way to calculate the median value over some grouped time-bucketed values. I see that there's multiple quantile functions that look very similar, but I can't understand what the difference is.

So my main question is: What is the difference between `APPROX_QUANTILE` and `APPROX_QUANTILE_DS` ?

Answer (score 2):

I [believe](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html#aggregation-functions) `APPROX_QUANTILE` allows you to use data stored using the [approxHistogram](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/approximate-histograms.html#approximate-histogram-aggregator) datasketch while `APPROX_QUANTILE_DS` is for the [Quantiles](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-quantiles.html) datasketch - and that because the former is [deprecated now](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/approximate-histograms.html#approximate-histogram-aggregator-deprecated) it's best to use the Quantiles datasketch.

Here's some blurb about the Quantiles sketch:
https://datasketches.apache.org/docs/Quantiles/QuantilesOverview.html

Hope this is actually useful....?!?!?!  haha!

Comment: I didn't know it was deprecated, so this was definitely useful. Thanks! :)